# Read text file in Python, separated by ',' and with ';' as line terminator

Tags: python, csv, pandas, text-files

My problem is that I have multiple text files with size of 200mb+ with this format (very little example):

```
john,smith,3;sasha,dilma,4;sofia,vergara,5;etc.
```

I need to read all those files and analyze the information, graph, sum, etc.

I've been thinking in different methods to save the data and use it in Python. However, the line terminator ';' is causing problems every time I try to load data into a DataBase or directly in Python (also tried with lineterminator parameter), for example:

```
import pandas as pd
userHeader = ['name', 'last_name', 'number']
users = pd.read_table('C:/prueba.txt', engine='python', sep=',', header=None, names=userHeader)

# print 3 first users
print '# 3 first users: \n%s' % users[:2]
```

Result:

```
# 3 first users: 
           name        last_name              number
0  john,smith,3  sasha,dilma,4  sofia,vergara,5
```

Edit. When I implement lineterminator just like this:

```
users = pd.read_table('C:/prueba.txt', engine='python', sep=',', lineterminator=';', header=None, names=userHeader)
```

I get the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-23a80631d090> in <module>()
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 userHeader = ['user_id', 'gender', 'age']
----> 3 users = pd.read_table('C:/prueba.txt', engine='python', sep=';', lineterminator=';', header=None, names=userHeader)
      4 
      5 # print 5 first users

C:\Users\molmos\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, dialect, compression, doublequote, escapechar, quotechar, quoting, skipinitialspace, lineterminator, header, index_col, names, prefix, skiprows, skipfooter, skip_footer, na_values, na_fvalues, true_values, false_values, delimiter, converters, dtype, usecols, engine, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, na_filter, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, warn_bad_lines, error_bad_lines, keep_default_na, thousands, comment, decimal, parse_dates, keep_date_col, dayfirst, date_parser, memory_map, float_precision, nrows, iterator, chunksize, verbose, encoding, squeeze, mangle_dupe_cols, tupleize_cols, infer_datetime_format, skip_blank_lines)
    472                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    473 
--> 474         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    475 
    476     parser_f.__name__ = name

C:\Users\molmos\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    248 
    249     # Create the parser.
--> 250     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    251 
    252     if (nrows is not None) and (chunksize is not None):

C:\Users\molmos\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    564             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    565 
--> 566         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    567 
    568     def _get_options_with_defaults(self, engine):

C:\Users\molmos\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in _make_engine(self, engine)
    709             elif engine == 'python-fwf':
    710                 klass = FixedWidthFieldParser
--> 711             self._engine = klass(self.f, **self.options)
    712 
    713     def _failover_to_python(self):

C:\Users\molmos\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in __init__(self, f, **kwds)
   1420         # Set self.data to something that can read lines.
   1421         if hasattr(f, 'readline'):
-> 1422             self._make_reader(f)
   1423         else:
   1424             self.data = f

C:\Users\molmos\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in _make_reader(self, f)
   1495         if sep is None or len(sep) == 1:
   1496             if self.lineterminator:
-> 1497                 raise ValueError('Custom line terminators not supported in '
   1498                                  'python parser (yet)')
   1499 

ValueError: Custom line terminators not supported in python parser (yet)
```

Do you have any idea of how to read and manipulate all this information stored in text files?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parameter `lineterminator=";"`.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""john,smith,3;sasha,dilma,4;sofia,vergara,5"""

userHeader = ['name', 'last_name', 'number']
users = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(temp), sep=',', lineterminator=";",header=None, names=userHeader)
print users
#    name last_name  number
#0   john     smith       3
#1  sasha     dilma       4
#2  sofia   vergara       5
```

You have to omit  `engine='python'`, because error:

> ValueError: Custom line terminators not supported in python parser (yet)

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html):

> **lineterminator** : string (length 1), default None,
>
> Character to break file into lines. Only valid with C parser

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the problem. Do you know what to do when you have a line terminator like this (with double ';') for example:

john,smith,3;;sasha,dilma,4;;sofia,vergara,5;;etc.

Comment: It has to be length 1, because it is implemented [this](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/parsers.py#L1517) way.

Answer (score 1):

`sep` is the separator for fields. The line terminator is given in `lineterminator`.

```
users = pd.read_table('C:/prueba.txt', engine='c', sep=',', lineterminator=';', header=None, names=userHeader)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lineterminator`:

```
df = pd.read_table('C:/prueba.txt', sep=',', lineterminator=';', header=None, names=userHeader)

In [62]: df
Out[62]:
    john    smith  3
0  sasha    dilma  4
1  sofia  vergara  5
```